# Polynomials at my school exam

Tags: polynomials

$f(x)$ is a Fermat polynomial if it can be expressed as a sum of squares of two polynomials with integer coefficients. Suppose $f(x)$ is a Fermat polynomial such that $f(0) =1000$. Prove that $f(x)+2x$ is not a Fermat polynomial.

It was the toughest question in my school exam. I somehow managed the constant terms of $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ but couldn't show that $f(x)+2x$ is not a Fermat polynomial.

Comment: What are $h,g$ ? is $f\equiv 1000$ or just for a specific $x$ ?

Comment: What do you mean by "$f(x)=1000$". Do you mean $f(x)$ is a constant polynomial, or that it takes on the value $1000$ for some particular value of $x$?

Comment: which school do you go to? it is an Olympiad problem  xP

Comment: An easy google search shows that this was a problem for the Regional Math Olympiad (RMO) for 2013.  Solutions for that contest are posted online.  http://olympiads.hbcse.tifr.res.in/uploads/crmo-2013-solutions-3

Comment: I live in jamshedpur and study in class 8 in Rajendra vidyalaya our school is ICSE board and in our exams we get such types of questions.

Answer (score 2):

> **Lemma** if $f$ is a Fermat polynomial such that $4|f(0)$ then $4$ divides the second coefficient of $f$ ( the corresponding coefficient to $x$)

*proof* : if $f(0)$ is divisible by $4$. write  $f(x) = g(x)^2+h(x)^2$ where $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ are polynomials with integer coeﬃcients. Hence easily we have  $g(0)^2 + h(0)^2$ is divisible by $4$. Since $g(0)$ and $h(0)$ are integers, their squares are either $1 \mod 4$ or $0 \mod 4$. It therefore follows that $g(0)$ and $h(0)$ are even. So the second 
coefficients in $g(x)^2$ and in $h(x)2$ (the corresponding to $x$) are both divisible by 4 because:
$$ (2a+bx+x^2k(x))^2=4a^2+(4ab)x+x^2(\cdots)$$
 so the second coefficient of $f(x)$ is divisible by $4$

Your question now is easy because $f(x)$ and $f(x)+2x$ cannot have both their second coefficients divisible by $4$

Comment: Thank for the answer man .